# How do I show an error for unauthorized can can access

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, cancan

I am using Bootstrap, which has `div class="alert notice"` that has a bunch of classes for various notice messages.

I also have an AJAX destroy action for a comment, that I have added `cancan` authorization on. When I try to delete a comment that the `current_user` doesn't have access to it doesn't work - which is correct.

But what I want to happen is for an error message to pop-up, in a Bootstrap style'd div for 5 - 10 seconds and then disappear.

This is the `destroy` action on my `CommentsController.rb`

```
  def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully deleted.'  }
          format.json { head :no_content }
          format.js   { render :layout => false }      
      else
          format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }  
      end
    end        
  end
```

Where I have the `@comment` set in a private method in the same controller:

```
  private
    def set_comment
      @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    end
```

This is my `comments/destroy.js.erb`

```
$('.delete_comment').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
        $(this).closest('div#new_comment').fadeOut();
});
```

But that doesn't affect unauthorized access.

In my `ability.rb`, I have this:

```
can :manage, Comment, user_id: user.id
```

In my log when I try to delete a comment that I don't have access to, I get this in my log:

```
Started DELETE "/comments/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-16 02:56:53 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  ReadMark Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "read_marks".* FROM "read_marks"  WHERE "read_marks"."user_id" = $1 AND "read_marks"."readable_type" = 'PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity' AND "read_marks"."readable_id" IS NULL  ORDER BY "read_marks"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."user_id" = $1 AND "comments"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 5]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 8ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=5 [WHERE "comments"."user_id" = $1]:
```

Which is perfect.

All I want to do is show an appropriate error in a Bootstrap alert that disappears in a few seconds.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first, if you use `cancan` - just use cancan:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource #this will set @comment by your ability and authorize action
  ...
end
```

This will raise `CanCan::AccessDenied` instead of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

Let's catch it in `ApplicationController` with rescue_from

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    @error_message = exception.message
    respond_to do |f|
      f.js{render 'errors/error', status: 401}
    end
  end
end
```

For popup notifications I use PNotify library http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/
It will show error in top right conner and then hide.
Just include it in your project and you can show the errors like this:

```
#app/views/errors/error.js.erb
new PNotify({
  title: 'Oh No!',
  text: '<%=@error_message%>',
  type: 'error'
});
```

This code lets you avoid of catching `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error as of bad practice.

**UPDATE**

I forgot something! You have to remove `set_comment` method and `before_action` or write it like this:

```
before_action :set_comment
...
private
def set_comment
  @comment ||= current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
end
```

This callback overwrote @comment variable from `load_and_authorize_resource` in your code.
Cancan makes this helper unneeded because it loads resource by `load_and_authorize_resource`

**UPDATE2**

You also need to make sure that you are using the latest version of cancan with `rails4` from [CanCanCommunity](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) because original old version doesn't support `rails4`

Just use this in you Gemfile

```
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.9'
```

instead of

```
gem 'cancan'
```

Comment: I like this....but, it doesn't work for me. I still get the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error in my logs and nothing happens on the front-end. By the way, I am using the `pnotify-rails` gem - https://github.com/navinpeiris/pnotify-rails

Comment: Should I do `load_and_authorize_resource` before the `before_action :set_comment` or after?

Comment: you may remove `before_action :set_comment`. `load_and_aurthorize_resource` do the same job.

Comment: When I do that, the authorization doesn't work at all - i.e. I am allowed to delete things I shouldn't be able to delete. Does that mean that my `ability.rb` rules are insufficient?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63293/discussion-between-railsme-and-marcamillion).

Answer (score 2):

In your `comments/destroy.js.erb` file add the following code:

```
<% if defined?(@error) %>
  $('.alert.notice').text("<%= @error %>");
  $('.alert.notice').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert.notice').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 5000);
<% end %>
```

Change the `set_comment` method to use `find_by` to avoid getting `RecordNotFound` exception:

```
def set_comment
  @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id:params[:id])
end
```

then in your controller you can modify the destroy action as follows:

```
def destroy
respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.present?
      @comment.destroy 
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully deleted.'  }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js   { render :layout => false }      
  else
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'unauthorized access error.'  }
      format.js { @error = 'unauthorized access error' }  
  end
end
```

end

Comment: This is nice and elegant, but doesn't work for me. I still get the ActiveRecord error.

Comment: ok please see my updated solution to get around the ActiveRecord error

Comment: @railsme Actually helped me figure it out. It was a cancan issue. I need to use cancancan.

Answer (score 0):

I place this in app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
## Handling unauthorized access: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#handle-unauthorized-access
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
      format.html { redirect_to main_app.root_url, notice: exception.message }
      format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
    end
  end
```