# How do I check CanCan abilities on an object in a `shared/partial`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancan

Per the `CanCan` documentation, to check if a user has the ability to do something to any element in the view, you do something like this:

```
<% if can? :create, @project %>
  <%= link_to "New Project", new_project_path %>
<% end %>
```

Or you can check with the class like:

```
<% if can? :create, Project %>
  <%= link_to "New Project", new_project_path %>
<% end %>
```

In my case, I have a `DashboardController#Index`, that has this:

```
@nodes = current_user.nodes.where(:is_comment => nil)
```

In my `views/dashboard/index.html.erb`, I have this:

```
      <% @nodes.each do |node| %>
            <!-- Upload Video Comment Popup -->
      <div class="box">
          <%= render partial: "shared/comments", locals: {node: node} %>
      </div>
      <% end %> <!-- node -->
```

Then in my `shared/_comments.html.erb`, I have this:

```
       <% if node.comments.present? %>
          <% node.comments.each do |comment| %>
             <% if can? :manage, Comment %> 
                Show Something Interesting Here                                                                 
             <% else %>
                 Show something boring here
              <% end %>                                                                 
           <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

That doesn't work.

I also tried this:

```
       <% if node.comments.present? %>
          <% node.comments.each do |comment| %>
             <% if can? :manage, comment %> 
                Show Something Interesting Here                                                                 
             <% else %>
                 Show something boring here
              <% end %>                                                                 
           <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

And that doesn't work either.

This is my `ability.rb`

```
can :manage, Comment, user_id: user.id
```

I thought about creating a `@comments` instance variable in the controller, but the issue with that is that the `comments` are on a collection of nodes (i.e. I need to show multiple nodes, and each node has multiple comments).

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last code should work after updating to CanCanCommunity version of cancan

```
<% if node.comments.present? %>
  <% node.comments.each do |comment| %>
     <% if can? :manage, comment %>
        Show Something Interesting Here
     <% else %>
         Show something boring here
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

related to [How do I show an error for unauthorized can can access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399269/how-do-i-show-an-error-for-unauthorized-can-can-access/26442991#26442991)

Comment: Awesome dude. You are on a roll today!